# Regular expression to stop at first found subpattern

Tags: php, regex

Let's take the next two examples in the consideration.

```
preg_match('/^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$/u', 'abcd', $matches);
preg_match('/^(\pL+)(?:d|cd|bcd)$/u', 'abcd', $matches);
```

Both examples return 'abc' as `$matches[1]`.

Why doesn't regex stop at first found subpattern in the non-matching group? Is is possible to stop at 'bcd' and get 'a' as `$matches[1]`?

Comment: Regex by default wants to be greedy.  Think about it, you are trying to **match** expressions.  If it can match a character, it will.  Say you have `/a+a/` on the string `aaaaaaaaaaa`.  Why would you match `aa` when you can match all the a's.

Comment: Probably for the same reason `^(\pL+)(?:d)$` return `abc` in $matches[1]. Try `^(\pL+)(?:bcd)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by making the `+` quantifier non-greedy:

```
preg_match('/^(\pL+?)(?:bcd|cd|d)$/u', 'abcd', $matches);
preg_match('/^(\pL+?)(?:d|cd|bcd)$/u', 'abcd', $matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete other answers, this is a schematic description of what happens:

```
str   | pattern              | state     | description
------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | SUCCESS   | all letters are matched by \pL+ (greedy)
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | FAIL      | there is no more character 
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | FAIL      | idem
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | FAIL      | idem
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | BACKTRACK | \pL+ give one character back
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | FAIL      | characters mismatch
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | FAIL      | idem
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | SUCCESS   |
abcd  | ^(\pL+)(?:bcd|cd|d)$ | SUCCESS   |
```

The most important to understand is that a quantifier is greedy by default and take all characters it can.

Note: This is a schema. In "real life" the regex engine works character by character. In the above example, when `bcd` is tested, the regex engine tests obviously only the `b` before failing.

Note 2: the second pattern will not have to test `bcd` and `cd` after the backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/^(\pL+?)(?>bcd|cd|d)$/u', 'abcd', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcd
    [1] => a
)
```